# Custom Control Libary WPF - DispatcherTimer não Inicia VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, wpf

Queria saber o por que do motivo desta função criada em uma `dll` para `WPF application` no `VS 2013` não inicia o `DispatcherTimer`.

Code:

```
Public Sub Iniciar
         TIniciaAntiDebuggers = New DispatcherTimer()
            AddHandler TIniciaAntiDebuggers.Tick, AddressOf TIniciaAntiDebuggers_Tick
            TIniciaAntiDebuggers.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
            TIniciaAntiDebuggers.Start()    
        End If
```

Event:

```
Private Sub TIniciaAntiDebuggers_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        AntiDebuggerOllyDbg()
    End Sub
```

Tentei de varias maneiras mas não consigo inicia o Evento Tick.. Lembrando que não é o **Timer** do `Windows.Forms` e sim o do `WPF == DispatcherTimer`

Answer (score 0):

**Solução:**
 Depois de muito eu tenta eu entendi o que houve de errado..

O Evento `Tick` do `DispatcherTimer` não iniciava por que eu não tinha Chamado uma `Thread` do tipo `STA`, eu fiz essa chamada apenas no WPF Application e não na DLL...

Então se vocês quiserem chamar o Evento `Tick` da DLL Desenvolvida para App's WPF vocês devem declarar a `Thread STA` no Formulario aonde chama a dll, na propria é só vocês chamar uma Thread normal ou seta-la também como `STA`.

**Exemplo:**
WPF Aplication

```
Dim ThreadWPFApplication As Thread

Public Sub IniciarThread
ThreadWPFApplication =  New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf IniciarDLL)
ThreadWPFApplication.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
ThreadWPFApplication.Start()
End sub

Public Sub IniciarDLL
''Chama a DLL
End Sub
```

DLL

```
Private WithEvents Tiniciar As DispatcherTimer
Dim IniciarThread As Thread

Public Sub New
  Me.Tiniciar = New System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer
  Me.Tiniciar.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2200)
  Me.Tiniciar.IsEnabled = True
End Sub

Public sub IniciarThread
''Aqui é apenas uma linha NADA MAIS, n precisa setar a **THREAD** como **STA**
IniciarThread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf IniciarDispatcherTimer)
End Sub

Public Sub IniciarDispatcherTimer()
  Me.Tiniciar = New System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer
  Me.Tiniciar.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2200)
  Me.Tiniciar.Start()
End Sub
```

Agora é só chama o evento Tick do IniciarThread 
:D Simples não?